# How to redirect another page in row jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I want to use link in row's JqGrid. This link get id from Row's click and redirect to another page and show another JqGrid.
I use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var searchOptions = ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'bw', 'bn', 'in', 'ni', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc'];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#list').jqGrid({
        caption: "ObisData",
        //url from wich data should be requested
        url: '@Url.Action("GetObisData", "DataGrid")',
        //EditData
        editurl: '@Url.Action("EditData", "DataGrid")',
        //type of data
        datatype: 'json',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "Rows",
            page: "Page",
            total: "Total",
            records: "Records",
            repeatitems: true,
            id: "ObisDataID",
            cell: "RowCells",
            subgrid: { root: "Rows", repeatitems: true, cell: "RowCells" }

        },
        //url access method type
        mtype: 'POST',

        //columns names
        colNames: ['', 'power', 'water', 'serial M', 'serial C', 'Date', ''],
        //columns model
        colModel: [
            {
                name: 'ObisDataID', index: 'ObisDataID', align: 'right', width: 100,
                editable: false, hidden: true, key: true
            },
        {
            name: 'MeterPowerSharingNo', index: 'MeterPowerSharingNo', align: 'center', width: 100,
            editable: false, hidden: false
        },
        {
            name: 'MeterWaterSharingNo', index: 'MeterWaterSharingNo', align: 'center', width: 100,
            editable: false, hidden: false
        }
        ,
        {
            name: 'ModemSerial', index: 'ModemSerial', align: 'center', width: 100,
            editable: false, hidden: false
        },
        {
            name: 'MeterSerial', index: 'MeterSerial', align: 'center', width: 100,
            editable: false, hidden: false
        }
         ,
        {
            name: 'MessageDate', index: 'MessageDate', align: 'center', width: 170,
            editable: false, hidden: false
        },
        {
            name: 'EditAction', index: 'EditAction', align: 'center', width: 170,
            formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                return "<a href='/DataGrid/GetAllObisData'><u>Show Detail</u></a>";
            }
        }

        ],
        //pager for grid
        pager: $('#pager'),
        //number of rows per page
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
        //initial sorting column
        sortname: 'ObisDataID',
        //initial sorting direction
        sortorder: 'desc',
        //we want to display total records count
        viewrecords: true,
        altRows: true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        width: '900',
        height: 'auto',
        hidegrid: false,
        direction: "rtl",
        gridview: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        footerrow: true,
        //userDataOnFooter: true,
        loadComplete: function () {
            //change alternate rows color
            $("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "#E0E0E0");
        },
        loadError: function (xhr, st, err) {
            jQuery("#rsperror").html("Type: " + st + "; Response: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        },
        subGrid: true,
        subGridModel: [{
            name: ['Data', 'translate'],
            width: [150, 150],
            align: ['center', 'center']
        }],
        subGridOptions: {
            reloadOnExpand: false //load only once
        },
        subGridUrl: '@Url.Action("GetSubGridObisData", "DataGrid")'
    });

});
```

but error when click 'show detail'.
[image]

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'page' of >non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetAllObisData(System.String, System.String, Int32, Int32, Boolean, System.String, System.String, System.String, System.String)' in 'MeterControl.Controllers.Grids.DataGridController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter"